# mitmproxy - filtering by domain?

Tags: mitmproxy

I am using `mitmproxy` for inspecting traffic for my app.
And want to see only traffic for my server.

How can I see only traffic for domain `*.some_domain.com`?

Answer (score 2):

For `mitmproxy`

```
mitmproxy --view-filter "~d .*\.some_domain\.com"
```

For `mitmdump`

```
mitmdump "~d .*\.some_domain\.com"
```